# Getting System.IO.FileNotFoundException in IIS but working in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I am building an application where i need to convert word file into .dat file. I have a UploadController.cs where i am uploading the word document to convert. This is working file in Visual studio but after publishing the code on IIS and when i am clicking on UploadController.cs button i am getting below error. I am not sure what i am missing here as it works fine in Local Visual Studio but not from IIS.[image: Error on IIS]

Comment: The assembly is likely not installed on the server you're deploying to.
It works in VS because that's running on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a referenced assembly is missing in the IIS server. In your Visual Studio project you will need to set Copy Local to True for the Interop assemblies. That way when you publish your site the referenced libraries will be copied along with your site and referenced from the copied files.